# How to make all drawn (rectangle, circles, lines, polygon) draggable? Pure JS

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, draggable, shapes

I have a simple paint canvas html5. Its can draw through a selection option some shapes like lines, circles, rectangles, polygon, but now i want to make all draws draggable if possible resizable, without 3 part library only pure JS.

```
    var canvas,
    context,
    dragStartLocation,
    snapshot;
    dragdrop = false;
    isDrag = false;




function resizeCanvas() {
        canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
        canvas.height = window.innerHeight;


}

function getCanvasCoordinates(event) {
    var x = event.clientX - canvas.getBoundingClientRect().left;
        y = event.clientY - canvas.getBoundingClientRect().top;

    return {x: x, y: y};
}



function takeSnapshot() {
    snapshot = context.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

}

function restoreSnapshot() {
    context.putImageData(snapshot, 0, 0);
}

function drawLine(position) {

    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(dragStartLocation.x, dragStartLocation.y);
    context.lineTo(position.x, position.y );
    context.stroke();

    }

function drawRect(position) {

    context.beginPath();
    //context.moveTo(dragStartLocation.x, dragStartLocation.y);
    context.fillRect(position.x, position.y, dragStartLocation.x - position.x, dragStartLocation.y - position.y);
    //context.stroke();

}

function drawCircle(position) {
    var radius = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((dragStartLocation.x - position.x), 2) + Math.pow((dragStartLocation.y - position.y), 2));
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(dragStartLocation.x, dragStartLocation.y, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);

}

/*
function drawPolygon(position, sides, angle) {
    var coordinates = [],
        radius = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((dragStartLocation.x - position.x), 2) + Math.pow((dragStartLocation.y - position.y), 2)),
        index = 0;

    for (index = 0; index < sides; index++) {
        coordinates.push({x: dragStartLocation.x + radius * Math.cos(angle), y: dragStartLocation.y - radius * Math.sin(angle)});
        angle += (2 * Math.PI) / sides;
    }

    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(coordinates[0].x, coordinates[0].y);
    for (index = 1; index < sides; index++) {
        context.lineTo(coordinates[index].x, coordinates[index].y);
    }

    context.closePath();
}*/


function draw(position) {

    var fillBox = document.getElementById("fillBox"),
        shape = document.querySelector('#tools option:checked').value,
        /*polygonSides = document.getElementById("polygonSides").value,
        polygonAngle = document.getElementById("polygonAngle").value,*/
        lineCap = document.querySelector('input[type="radio"][name="lineCap"]:checked').value;
        /*composition = document.querySelector('input[type="radio"][name="composition"]:checked').value;*/

    context.lineCap = lineCap;
    /*context.globalCompositeOperation = composition;*/

    if (shape === "circle") {
        drawCircle(position);

    }
    if (shape === "line") {
        drawLine(position);
    }

    if (shape === "rect") {
        drawRect(position);
    }

    if (shape === "polygon") {
        drawPolygon(position, polygonSides, polygonAngle * (Math.PI / 180));
    }

    if (shape !== "line") {
        if (fillBox.checked) {
            context.fill();
        } else {
            context.stroke();
        }
    }
}

function dragStart(event) {
    dragging = true;
    dragStartLocation = getCanvasCoordinates(event);
    takeSnapshot();
}

function drag(event) {
    var position;
    if (dragging === true) {
        restoreSnapshot();
        position = getCanvasCoordinates(event);
        draw(position);
    }
}

function dragStop(event) {
    dragging = false;
    restoreSnapshot();
    var position = getCanvasCoordinates(event);
    draw(position);
}

function changeLineWidth() {
    context.lineWidth = this.value;
    event.stopPropagation();
}

function changeFillStyle() {
    context.fillStyle = this.value;
    event.stopPropagation();
}

function changeStrokeStyle() {
    context.strokeStyle = this.value;
    event.stopPropagation();
}

function changeBackgroundColor() {
    context.save();
    context.fillStyle = document.getElementById("backgroundColor").value;
    context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    context.restore();
}

function eraseCanvas() {
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}


function init() {
    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var lineWidth = document.getElementById("lineWidth"),
        fillColor = document.getElementById("fillColor"),
        strokeColor = document.getElementById("strokeColor"),
        //canvasColor = document.getElementById("backgroundColor"),
        clearCanvas = document.getElementById("clearCanvas");
        //saveCanvas = document.getElementById("saveCanvas");

    context.strokeStyle = strokeColor.value;
    context.fillStyle = fillColor.value;
    context.lineWidth = lineWidth.value;

    /*window.addEventListener('resize', resizeCanvas, false);
    window.addEventListener('orientationchange', resizeCanvas, false);
    resizeCanvas();*/


    canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', dragStart, false);
    canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', drag, false);
    canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', dragStop, false);
    lineWidth.addEventListener("input", changeLineWidth, false);
    fillColor.addEventListener("input", changeFillStyle, false);
    strokeColor.addEventListener("input", changeStrokeStyle, false);
    //canvasColor.addEventListener("input", changeBackgroundColor, false);
    clearCanvas.addEventListener("click", eraseCanvas, false);
    //saveCanvas.addEventListener("click", salvaCanvas, false);

}

window.addEventListener('load', init, false);
```

Comment: There are many (dozens?) of questions/answers on Stackoverflow relating to "dragging" canvas drawings. I suspect a search will quickly reveal the code you need ;-)

Answer (score 1):

It is an essential feature of canvas that it stores only the raster image formed as a result of all the draw operations. This why canvas is fast and memory efficient.

The downside is that you have to erase the affected rectangle on the canvas (or the whole canvas in the worst case) and redraw all the shapes that need to be resized, moved, etc. The canvas does not store them as objects, so your JS code must take care of storing, modifying and re-drawing them on the canvas. The effort is substantial unless you use some third party library.

The alternative is to use SVG-like features of HTML5 instead of canvas: `<line>`, `<path>`, `<rect>`, etc. They are kept as objects by the browser and accessible via DOM. This is a totally different approach, however, and requires a full rewrite of your code.

Comment: An example of draggable SVG can be found [here](http://www.petercollingridge.co.uk/interactive-svg-components/draggable-svg-element). No libs used as all, even jQuery.

Comment: But in my code is possible to adapt it? And if i use a third party library line jcanvas how can i use it with my code only to drag and drop?

Comment: The SVG approach is an alternative to yours, I see no way to combine the two. It is possible to continue using canvas, but then your script must keep a list of all shapes drawn, detect the shape being dragged/resized, and re-draw all the shapes on mouse moves. Unfortunately, I have no ready solution in pure JS.

Comment: @MikeBessonov. Upvote for the article you cite by Peter Collingridge which gives a nice concise way to drag SVG elements with no jQuery :-) BTW, the questioner appears to want to export the SVG as an image which will ironically bring you back to using a canvas element as an export vehicle. ;-)

Comment: @markE. Good point. If the final intent is to export the sketch as a raster, then I would still edit it in vector (SVG), and in the end just slap the SVG image on the canvas and let the browser render it, as described at http://getcontext.net/read/svg-images-on-a-html5-canvas .

Comment: @MikeBessonov. You might include the code from your links into your answer in case the links go dead ;-)